# Setting SESSION elements inside php using data sent from Android

Tags: php, android, session, http-headers

I am trying to send data from Android to php which has to save the data in **SESSION**. However, my session is still empty. On the other side, when I set SESSION from a website, it works. I assume it is because of

```
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

line inside my js(for testing purposes).
What is the equivalent line for Android?
In my Android I have:

```
httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
String url = "http://www.weddingwatch.org/WebGL/Testing/" + myTablet + "saveCoordinates.php";
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);  
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data[0], HTTP.CONTENT_ENCODING));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Isn't "**HTTP.CONTENT_ENCODING**" not suitable for sending data to a server for later process such as setting SESSION elements?

Comment: You're asking about the session on the server side but you post client-side code...

Comment: What are you using to test if the session variable is set?

Comment: HTTP.CONTENT_ENCODING is about how you encode the content (UTF-8 for instance)

Comment: From a client side I use ajax call to sens data to php. After ajax call is sent, I use another ajax call which get the session elements and outputs on my screen. I do these for testing purposes to make sure that my server side code is correct.

Comment: What should I use instead of HTTP.Content_encoding so my data will be available for a server side for setting SESSION elements?

Comment: Thanks Alfasin, Wayne, and Aerilys for help

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution to my problem. In order to find a SESSION elements, you have to specify SESSION ID otherwise it get mixed with other SESSION elements.
Hopefully, my assumption is correct. Thus, after I set a Session id inside my php, I was able to retrieve that elements later in the process.